# How to write to plist successfully?

Tags: iphone, plist

I am having trouble writing my file into the plist after going through many tutorials, other people's problems and attempting it for myself. I can read the plist with no problems but I cant update it. Below are my codes on how I am writing my data into the plist. Correct me if I made any mistake.

```
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"EventAddress" ofType:@"plist"]; 
    NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSArray* allmyData = [myDictionary  allValues];

    // creates and array to store only the event details
    NSMutableArray *data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:allmyData];
    [data addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:tfAddress.text, @"Address", tvEvents.text, @"Events", nil]];
    [myDictionary setValue:data forKey:@"Whampo"];
    BOOL flag = [myDictionary writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
    if (flag){
        NSLog(@"write to plist success");
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", myDictionary);
    [myDictionary release];
```

The path is correct, the file exists, my values in the textView and textField are in the array, but when it comes to the writeToFile, it does not reflect on the file located at the document directory.

**EDIT 01:**

I found this online, very similar to Nekto's suggestion. But I am thinking on how to implement my code with his. I think its pretty simple, but I cant seem to figure out how to.

```
NSArray *paths= NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *plistDirectory = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Enterprise",documentDirectory];

NSString *mPath = [plistDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Downloads.plist"]; 

[mDownloadsArray writeToFile:mPath atomically:YES];
```

[iphonesdk.blogspot](http://iphonesdevsdk.blogspot.com/2011/04/plist.html) taken from that site.

**EDIT 02:**

I used Nekto's suggestion and it worked well. But I am curious why it is returning DocumentsEventAddress.plist rather than EventAddress.plist. My assumption is because of the 
`NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    NSString *plistPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingString:@"EventAddress.plist"];`

Where rootPath is returning `Document` is that right?

Comment: May be replace `NSString *documentDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];` => `NSString *documentDirectory = [paths lastObject];`

Comment: I didnt even use the `NSString *documentDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];` in the first place... :P But yea, I will remember that in my testing of codes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm writing to file in such way:

```
NSString *errorDesc = nil;
NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *plistPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingString:TEMPLATES_PATH];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:templates forKey:@"templates"];
NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:dict format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&errorDesc];
if (plistData)
{
    [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
}else
{
    NSLog(@"[Error] Application Did Enter Background {saving file error}: %@", errorDesc);
    [errorDesc release];
}
```

Be sure to save file in app documents directory.

Comment: is this the wrong approach? I replaced this line: `NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"EventAddress" ofType:@"plist"]; ` with this: `NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];` The code didn't even write a plist file, and the documents directory didn't have the file either.  I thought it would work by replacing

Comment: In `rootPath` you will have only path to App Doc directory. Just add **filename** and all will be ok! For example, `NSString *path = [rootPath stringByAppendingString:@"EventAddress.plist"];` and use `path` in `writeToFile:` method.

Comment: OK! I go try that out. I hope it really works, been working on this for weeks! **EDIT:** sadly, it didnt work... I must be missing some steps here :(

Comment: Wasn't file created in App Doc Directory?

Comment: Try this : `NSString *path = [rootPath stringByAppendingString:@"/EventAddress.plist"];`

Comment: It supposed to be created, but now when I attempt your method. I deleted the whole folder from the document directory and hope it would work... I didnt want to do a clean target.

Comment: I just recalled that I read on another link here that I have to copy the existing file onto an array add the new objects into the array BEFORE updating the plist. Do I need to do that first?

Comment: I am stuck at this line `NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:templates forKey:@"templates"];` How am I suppose to replace this line with my dictionary?

Comment: You can use your own variant. I posted code to help you understand my approach.

Comment: Alright, thanks. It is sort of working now. But it is not the way I expected. I see what I can do on my side.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can write to a resource. Only files in the documents directory can be written to.

Answer (score 0):

You can't write to files that are located in you Bundle.
The app bundle is read only.

Comment: Ok, will try @Nekto suggestion regarding to your reply :)

Comment: Apparently, it did not. I have a feeling I am doing it wrongly, but by looking at his code. I can't seem to know how to fit my code with his, to make it work