# Objective c writing UISwitch state in a plist for a key

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to write to plist successfully?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254596/how-to-write-to-plist-successfully)

I want to simply write the boolean state of a UISwitch(true or false) in a Plist file.

Here is what I already got, but the values do not change in the plist:

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {


    IBOutlet UISwitch *mySwitch;

}

-(IBAction)changeThingsInPlist:(id)sender;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

BOOL changeThing;
#define PLIST_PATH @"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.myname.plistname.plist"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    changeThing = [[[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:PLIST_PATH]valueForKey:@"changeThing"]boolValue];

}

-(IBAction)changeThingsInPlist:(id)sender {

    if (mySwitch.on = YES) {
        changeThing = true;
    }
    else {
        changeThing = false;
    }
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

I simply want to change the value(true or false) in the plist file by switching the uiswitch.

should I use NSUserDefaults? :)

I read into it, but I never got, how to set the plist path in the NSUserDefaults

Thank you

Comment: why don't you use the `NSUserDefaults` for this individual value instead?

Comment: Just follow the accepted answer on this question,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254596/how-to-write-to-plist-successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that you should create an NSString and set the value of it based on the boolean value of the UISwitch.

```
NSString *valueOfSwitch;
if (mySwitch.on == YES){
valueOfSwitch = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ON"];
}
else {
valueOfSwitch = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"OFF"];
}
```

Then you should put that string in the NSUserDefaults like so.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:valueOfSwitch forKey:@"switchValue"];   //remember this for retrieving
[defaults synchronize];
```

Then to retrieve this string you do this.

```
NSUserDefaults *data = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *switchString = [data objectForKey:@"switchValue"]; //same key that you used for saving
[data synchronize];
```

From there you can do whatever you want with that string.